# How can I get older versions of kubectl for arm64 (MacBook Pro M1)

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

Kuberenetes repo doesn't have older `kubectl` versions for ARM64 (M1 Apple Silicon), the newest version are available with the command :

```
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/darwin/arm64/kubectl"
```

v1.21 being the oldest available with this command for ARM64.

But I need kubectl v1.10, how can I build kubectl v1.10 for ARM64 architecture from the source code or even get it already built from some other repo?

When trying to build

```
cd examples/kubectl-container 

make kubectl
make -C ../../ WHAT=cmd/kubectl KUBE_STATIC_OVERRIDES="kubectl"; \
    cp ../../_output/local/bin/darwin/arm64/kubectl .
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
cp: ../../_output/local/bin/darwin/arm64/kubectl: No such file or directory
make: *** [kubectl] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you tried the commands I suggested instead of your own?

Comment: @jksoegaard yes, but get `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with compiling software? - Have you unpacked the file and entered into the folder before running make?

Comment: @jksoegaard yes I did, I also tried the example folder see edit in the question above

Comment: Well, the message you have says that you did not do it :-) So let's take it one step at a time. You have the unapcked code and there's a folder named "kubernetes-1.10.13" - you need to cd into that folder and then run make.

Comment: @jksoegaard you are right but now I get 
 go mod init
go: cannot find main module, but found Godeps/Godeps.json in /Users/eduardflorinescu/Downloads/kubernetes-1.10.13/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes
 to create a module there, run:
 go mod init +++ [0824 13:16:02] Building the toolchain targets:
    k8s.io/kubernetes/hack/cmd/teststale
    k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata
go install: version is required when current directory is not in a module

Comment: Try 'go install k8s.io/kubernetes/hack/cmd/teststale@latest k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata@latest' to install the latest version
!!! [0824 13:16:02] Call tree:
!!! [0824 13:16:02]  1: /Users/eduardflorinescu/Downloads/kubernetes-1.10.13/hack/lib/golang.sh:675 kube::golang::build_kube_toolchain(...)
!!! [0824 13:16:02]  2: hack/make-rules/build.sh:27 kube::golang::build_binaries(...)
make[1]: *** [_output/bin/deepcopy-gen] Error 1
make: *** [generated_files] Error 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128888/discussion-between-eduard-florinescu-and-jksoegaard).

Comment: @jksoegaard seems there are some issues for arm64
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/74965

Comment: Those issues do not seem relevant here as they concern docker builds. You're doing a go build. Have you ensured you have the latest go toolchain installed?

Comment: @jksoegaard I don't know what that implies,
is it go install k8s.io/kubernetes/hack/cmd/teststale@latest k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/go-bindata@latest]

Comment: @jksoegaard seems to be this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34067

Comment: Nope - that doesn't seem to be the issue. If you note, it is listed as an issue for a much older version. So not the case here. Have you seen the questions I have asked you in the chat?

Comment: Why do you an old version?

Comment: @mmmmmm old version  on the kube-apiserver

Comment: Fair enough but you are aware that v1.10 is obselete and probably a security risk "Furthermore, we expect to "support" three minor releases at a time. "Support" means we expect users to be running that version in production"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kubectl` version 1.10 is from March 2018. The Apple M1 chip was launched in November 2020. There would not have been any builds available of `kubectl` 1.10 for the M1 chip when it was made - and I don't think it is likely that anyone would be producing builds for public usage for several year old versions of `kubectl` for the M1.

You will simply have to download the source code for the 1.10 version and compile it yourself. You might experience that it won't compile or that it won't work when compiled - in that case you'll have to backport fixes for the M1 support from the newer releases to the 1.10 release.

You can download the source code from here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/archive/refs/tags/v1.10.13.tar.gz

You can build the source code in two ways. The first is to first ensure you have a working Go installation, unpack the source code and then use the Terminal to run:

```
make
```

Or alternative you need a working Docker command line installation, and then you need to run:

```
make quick-release
```